# String.Index encodedOffset is deprecated, but the alternative suggested does not work

Tags: swift

I'm a bit confused by Apples warning that:

```swift
'init(encodedOffset:)' is deprecated: 
encodedOffset has been deprecated as most common usage is incorrect.
Use String.Index(utf16Offset:in:) to achieve the same behavior.
```

Because `encodedOffset` and `utf16Offset` are not the same thing. In my case I'm getting string indexes from an external source, these indexes are in utf8 byte offsets.

Take this string: `"‍‍‍"`. This is 25 utf8 bytes long. 22 utf16 bytes long(which Apple calls a utf16.count of 11).

What I'm receiving from the server is the range `{0, 25}`.

The following works:

```swift
let index = String.Index(encodedOffset: 25)
string[string.startIndex..<index] // "‍‍‍"
```

Apple has suggested to replace this with `String.Index(utf16Offset:in:)`

```swift
let index = String.Index(utf16Offset: 25, in: string)
string[string.startIndex..<index] // Fatal error: String index range is out of bounds
```

The `utf16Offset` would be 11, not 25, and until I can get the substring, there's no way to calculate that 25 bytes in utf8 is 11 utf16 double bytes because that's dependent on the particulars of the string.

This also doesn't work

```swift
String.UTF8View.Index(utf16Offset: 25, in: string)
```

How can I get a utf8 bytes offset in a String with `utf16Offset:in:`?

[Swift 5: String.UTF16View.Index(encodedOffset: l) deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378537/swift-5-string-utf16view-indexencodedoffset-l-deprecated)

This question is not a duplicate of the above question because it appears in that question the answer is dealing with utf16, not utf8.

The github post here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0241-string-index-explicit-encoding-offset.md implies there is a utf8 alternative:

```
/// The UTF-8 code unit offset corresponding to this Index
public func offset<S: StringProtocol>(in utf8: S.UTF8View) -> Int { ... }
```

But I can't find it anywhere else.

EDIT: Here's the code that got it working for me, I'm not sure why I gave that `utf16Offset` warning any credence.

Thanks @Itai

```swift
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
  func attributedSubstring(utf8Range: NSRange) -> NSAttributedString {
    let range = rangeIn(utf8Range: utf8Range)
    return attributedSubstring(from: range ?? .zero)
  }

  func rangeIn(utf8Range range: NSRange) -> NSRange? {
    let utf8 = string.utf8
    guard let lowerBound = utf8.index(utf8.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: utf8.endIndex)?.samePosition(in: string.utf16) else { return nil }
    guard let upperBound = utf8.index(lowerBound, offsetBy: range.length, limitedBy: utf8.endIndex)?.samePosition(in: string.utf16) else { return nil }
    return NSRange(lowerBound ..< upperBound, in: string)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let nsmas = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "‍‍‍!‍‍‍")
if let range = nsmas.rangeIn(utf8Range: NSMakeRange(26, 25)) {
  nsmas.attributedSubstring(from: range) // "‍‍‍"
}
```

Or just:

```swift
nsmas.attributedSubstring(utf8Range: NSMakeRange(26, 25)) // "‍‍‍"
```

Comment: Not a part of the answer, but that `offset(in: String.UTF8View)` API you're referencing is part of the "Alternatives Considered" section of SE-0241; it indeed does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working explicitly with UTF-8 code units (bytes), it makes the most sense to work directly with [`String.UTF8View`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/utf8view); specifically, because `UTF8View` is a `Collection` of UTF-8 code units, offsetting a `UTF8View.Index` by a number will advance it by that many units.

Given a UTF-8 code unit range and a `String`, you'd achieve this as follows:

```
let (lower, upper) = (0, 25)
let str = "‍‍‍ Hello, family!"
let utf8View = str.utf8

let start = utf8View.index(utf8View.startIndex, offsetBy: lower)
let end = utf8View.index(utf8View.startIndex, offsetBy: upper)
print(str[start ..< end]) // => "‍‍‍"
```

Internally, the [`index(_:offsetBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/index(_:offsetby:)) operation does pretty much exactly what you're doing, in a stable way: it [fetches the `encodedOffset` of the index](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1611f70ff1da299a6f36a89aca3cbd6fbb4a100/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8View.swift#L166), advances it by the offset you pass in, then creates [a new index with that encoded offset](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1611f70ff1da299a6f36a89aca3cbd6fbb4a100/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8View.swift#L169C14-L169C54). This should be as performant as using the deprecated `encodedOffset` APIs, with the benefit of being much clearer than "encoded offset" (which doesn't mean much).

If you find yourself performing this operation a lot, you can write some helpers to do this.

Comment: Awesome. This is what I ended up going with. I've done this `index(_:offsetBy:)` operation a thousand times, but something about the warning saying `utf16Offset` being the same as `encodedOffset` through me off. I've added my code as an edit to my question in case it's helpful to anyone in the future. It's doing basically what you've outlined here, but as an extension on `NSAttributedString`. Thanks for the response, answer accepted.

Comment: @PeterR BTW, SE-0241 (and the deprecation warning) both mention using `utf16Offset:` because at the time of writing, `encodedOffset` _was_ a UTF-16 offset. SE-0241 was written in the Swift 4 timeframe, and in Swift 5, `String` switched to UTF-8-by-default, which also changed the meaning of `encodedOffset`. (Hence deprecating it prior to Swift 5, because it was known the meaning would change.)